# Timeout after 30s waiting on dependencies to become available: [tcp://mathesar_db:5432]

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, mathesar

I tried running `sudo docker compose --profile dev up` but everytime it fails to bring the server up with the same exact reason - **Timeout after 30s waiting**. I also tried restarting the docker service and killing all the processes on port 5432, but it didn't help.

```bash
[+] Running 3/0
 ⠿ Container mathesar_db            Created                                0.0s
 ⠿ Container mathesar_service_dev   Cr...                                  0.0s
 ⠿ Container mathesar-watchtower-1  C...                                   0.0s
Attaching to mathesar-watchtower-1, mathesar_db, mathesar_service_dev
mathesar-watchtower-1  | time="2023-03-24T06:55:57Z" level=debug msg="Sleeping for a second to ensure the docker api client has been properly initialized."
mathesar_db            | 
mathesar_db            | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
mathesar_db            | 
mathesar_db            | 2023-03-24 06:55:57.217 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.10 (Debian 13.10-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
mathesar_db            | 2023-03-24 06:55:57.218 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
mathesar_db            | 2023-03-24 06:55:57.218 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
mathesar_db            | 2023-03-24 06:55:57.384 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
mathesar_db            | 2023-03-24 06:55:57.550 UTC [26] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-03-24 06:55:17 UTC
mathesar_db            | 2023-03-24 06:55:57.595 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
mathesar-watchtower-1  | time="2023-03-24T06:55:58Z" level=debug msg="Making sure everything is sane before starting"
mathesar-watchtower-1  | time="2023-03-24T06:55:58Z" level=debug msg="Retrieving running containers"
mathesar-watchtower-1  | time="2023-03-24T06:55:58Z" level=debug msg="There are no additional watchtower containers"
mathesar-watchtower-1  | time="2023-03-24T06:55:58Z" level=info msg="Watchtower 1.5.3"
mathesar-watchtower-1  | time="2023-03-24T06:55:58Z" level=info msg="Using no notifications"
mathesar-watchtower-1  | time="2023-03-24T06:55:58Z" level=info msg="Only checking containers using enable label"
mathesar-watchtower-1  | time="2023-03-24T06:55:58Z" level=info msg="Periodic runs are not enabled."
mathesar-watchtower-1  | time="2023-03-24T06:55:58Z" level=info msg="The HTTP API is enabled at :8080."
mathesar_service_dev   | 2023/03/24 06:55:58 Waiting for: tcp://mathesar_db:5432
mathesar_service_dev   | 2023/03/24 06:56:28 Timeout after 30s waiting on dependencies to become available: [tcp://mathesar_db:5432]
mathesar_service_dev exited with code 1
```

For the first time, restarting the docker service did work. But after I updated the code and run `sudo docker compose --profile dev up`  again, the service exited every time I tried.

I also tried with docker-compose instead of docker compose, got same result.

Removed docker completely and installed again, still same problem.

OS: Ubuntu 22.10 (Kinetic Kudu).

**Edit:** I have increased the connection timeout. Now showing `Problem with dial: dial tcp 172.18.0.3:5432: connect: connection timed out. Sleeping 1s`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I think this was solved in Mathesar's Matrix channels, and turned out to be a problem with your Docker setup.

Comment: Hi, @DominykasMostauskis, Yes, I think it's a problem with my docker setup. I tried many solutions available online, but nothing fixed this.